# Добавил в свое android приложение просмотр YouTube плеера. У некоторых пользователей вылетает такая ошибка: Не удалось запустить проигрыватель YouTube

Tags: android, youtube, мобильные-приложения, плеер

Добавил в свое android приложение просмотр встроенного YouTube плеера. Но у некоторых пользователей при запуске видео вылетает такая ошибка: Не удалось запустить проигрыватель YouTube.
Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка может возникать на 11 версии из-за ограничений на доступ к внешним приложениям. Добавьте в манифест следующее:

```
<queries>
   <intent>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
   </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Получилось!